# React-native-calendars initialDate showing on each month

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

When I give an initial date it is marked for all months on the calendar how can I avoid that ?

```
<Agenda
          items={items}
          loadItemsForMonth={loadItems}
          current={'2022-10-28'}
          showClosingKnob={true}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          theme={{
            dotColor: "#22F460", 
          }}
          markingType={'custom'}
          markedDates={marked}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Agenda with CalendarProvider and add date prop = ""

```
<CalendarProvider date="">
    <Agenda
      items={items}
      loadItemsForMonth={loadItems}
      ...
    />
</CalendarProvider>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).